# How to wrap to text when text is long

Tags: jasper-reports

I have made a report In which I want to wrap words When the text is longer than the line But the result is the text has been entered below the line Causing all results to be out of line. How to......

```
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="259" y="2" width="48" height="17"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                <font fontName="AngsanaUPC" size="13" pdfFontName="AngsanaUPC" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{TRDATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="312" y="2" width="113" height="17"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="AngsanaUPC" size="13" pdfFontName="AngsanaUPC" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LOCATION}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="426" y="2" width="58" height="17"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="AngsanaUPC" size="14" pdfFontName="AngsanaUPC" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{SAVENAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="486" y="2" width="59" height="17"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="AngsanaUPC" size="13" pdfFontName="AngsanaUPC" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{SAVEDATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="10" y="18" width="535" height="1"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </line>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="11" y="1" width="33" height="17"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="AngsanaUPC" size="13" pdfFontName="AngsanaUPC" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{SEQ}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="47" y="2" width="212" height="16"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="AngsanaUPC" size="13" pdfFontName="AngsanaUPC" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COURSENAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Example output for report:

[image: Example output from jasper report]

Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all the elements in the band and set Stretch type = "Relative to Tallest Objest"